# Can an associate professor be a postdoc supervisor

Tags: postdocs, supervision, associate-professor

I am a young researcher searching for a postdoctoral studies. I found a researcher that works in a field similar to mine and I have in mind a project for postdoctoral studies supervised by her.

However, she is not a full professor. In fact she has been named as an associate professor just a year ago. Is it appropriate for an associate professor to be a supervisor for postdoctoral studies in this case?

Comment: Why would that not be possible?

Comment: In my department, associate professors can certainly supervise postdocs, but it seems quite possible that other universities, and especially other countries, may have different rules.

Comment: In my institution in the United States, you need not even be an assistant professor to supervise post doctoral fellows. Whether that's a good idea for the post doc is another question...

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you don't mean a part time faculty member, yes, it it possible. The only real issue is whether she has, or can obtain, funding to support you.

Supervising a postdoc would be a boost to her career as well.

You should ask her what the possibility is and what funding is available. Describe the project or research arc you have in mind.

Comment: I would think that even a not-full-time professor could supervise a postdoc and graduate students. Various job-share appointments and other posts that enable work-family balance should not impair the ability to actually perform all aspects of the job.

Comment: I meant full professor. My apologies!